# SonarQube: Validation of project failed, Module is already part of project

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to analyze one Maven project (with the SonarQube Scanner for Maven) and I am getting the following validation error: Module "com.company:module1" is already part of project "com.company".
I would like to ask you if there is a way to turn this validation off or what should I do in order to analyze the project the second project without deleting the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to turn this validation off; component keys must be unique across the instance. To be able to analyze both projects, you must remove ([or exclude](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)) the module from one of the projects. If the already-analyzed project is the one that loses the module, make your configuration changes, re-analyze, and *then* you should be able to analyze the second project.